# python sqlite3 database error(error binding parameter probably unsupported type) problem

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

My main code to call the database function is,

```
val = [''] * 4
mulq = [''] * 4
for i in range(len(multiplels)):
    for j in range(len(multiplels[i])):
        if j == 0:
            mulq[j] = StringVar()
            q2label = Label(lframe, textvariable=mulq[j])
            q2label.grid(row=rownum, column=0, pady=5)
            mulq[j].set('# '+str(multiplels[i][j]))
            rownum += 1
        else:
            val[i] = IntVar()
            mulq[j] = StringVar()
            a = Radiobutton(lframe, textvariable=mulq[j], value=j, variable=val[i])
            a.grid(row=rownum, column=0, sticky='w')
            mulq[j].set(str(multiplels[i][j]))
            rownum += 1
```

database call code is,

```
savingmulans(pcode, code, name, reg, val)
```

database function is,

```
def savingmulans(pcode, ecode, name, reg, mulans):  # --------------------- Multiple answer mark
    db_con = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
    print("Created")
    curs = db_con.cursor()
    for i in range(len(mulans)):
        # a = mulans[i]
        curs.execute("INSERT INTO Student_Tab(Name, Id, Examcode, Papercode, MultipleAnswer) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);",
                     (name, reg, ecode, pcode, mulans))

    db_con.commit()
    curs.close()
    db_con.close()
```

here error message is,

> line 263, in savingmulans
>       (name, reg, ecode, pcode, mulans))
>   sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 4 - probably unsupported type.

type of variables are name-text, id-integer, ecode-text, pcode-text, multipleanswer-text. because of error I changed the type to multipleanswer-integer. I can't understand what is wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @BryanOakley Mr. can you help?

Comment: What *python* type is the value of `pcode`?

Comment: @Shawn stringvariable type